# Org mode clock report shift day range

Tags: org-mode, org-clock-table

I use org-mode clocks to keep track of my work hours, and the timesheet is expected to be grouped by day. The thing is, I sometimes work late at night, and the daily view shows work splitted up like this:

```
  Daily report: [2017-01-11 Wed]
  | Headline                                   | Time   |      |
  |--------------------------------------------+--------+------|
  | *Total time*                               | *1:06* |      |
  |--------------------------------------------+--------+------|
  | something                                  | 1:06   |      |
  | \emsp Some task                            |        | 1:06 |

  Daily report: [2017-01-12 Thu]
  | Headline                                   | Time   |      |
  |--------------------------------------------+--------+------|
  | *Total time*                               | *3:10* |      |
  |--------------------------------------------+--------+------|
  | something                                  | 3:10   |      |
  | \emsp Some task                            |        | 3:10 |
```

Is there any way to have the clocking command put all hours in the first day's report? Maybe by providing an offset for when a day starts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you use something like `:block thisweek` and `:step day`. I am not aware of a way to set an offset for this setup but there's a way to have one report per "day"/24h. For this, you have to create a clocktable for each day and instead of `:block` and `:step` you specifiy the start and end with `:tstart` and `:tend`, e.g. `:tstart "[2017-01-30 Mon 06:00]" :tend "[2017-01-31 Tue 06:00]"`.

To automate things, you can use `org-clone-subtree-with-time-shift` for copying the clocktable with a time shift of one day, e.g. `M-x org-clone-subtree-with-time-shift 6 +1d`. This way, you can create the clocktables for one week, and if you have that, you can clone the subtree with the week clocktables again with a timeshift of `+1w` to get as many clocktables as you'd like to have.

While this is not as convenient as having one table per week, it has the advantage that you don't commit to a fixed "end-of-day time". In case, you start early one day, you can always adjust the clocktable for that day only.

Comment: Aha! This is an even better solution than what I had in mind. One more question: is it possible to merge these tables into one big table in the format date - time spent (date for each day), perhaps for easy exporting to excel and whatnot?